# If the value of an input is greater than 0 dynamically populate other inputs on a page

Tags: javascript

Right now I'm using javascript to get the job done but i'm using onkeyup. This won't work for me because i'm using a button to populate the "var first". When a user pushes the button it populates the var first so there is no actual keyup/keydown.

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
  var first = document.getElementById('USERDEFINE1'),
      //second = document.getElementById('ADDRESS2');
      third = document.getElementById('PHONENIGHT');
      fourth = document.getElementById('INTERNET');
      fifth = document.getElementById('last_purchase');
      sixth = document.getElementById('last_purchase_date');


  first.onkeyup = function () { // or first.onchange
    //second.value = '4444';
    third.value = '111-111-1111';
    fourth.value = 'NONE';
    fifth.value = 'N/A';
    sixth.value = 'N/A';
  };
};
</script>
```

could i use something like:

```
if (document.getElementById(first.value) > 0
```

and if so how do i implement into my current javascript or should i rewrite it all together?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `if (+first.value > 0) { }`

Comment: Why the jQuery tag if you are not using it?

Comment: I don't see the jquery tag, which tag are you referring to? Also, I'm slightly confused on how to integrate that Ian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will simply have to run the same population logic after pressing the button **and** after pressing a key in that input. You can also rely on other events like `change`, depending on how dynamic you want your interface to be.

Basically,

```
function populateInputs() {
    //if we are in here, it means the value of first is > than 0
    //at this point you can populate your other inputs
}

document.getElementById('your-button-id').addEventListener('click', function () {
    first.value = 10; //init the value greater than 0
    populateInputs(); //we know value is greater so populate
});

first.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
    if (first.value > 0) {
        populateInputs();
    } else {
        //first.value is not greater than 0
        //reset input values to N/A or blank?
    }
});
```

Comment: yourButton = id of my button? Also in //populate is that where I would add function populateInputs() {
    third.value = '111-111-1111';
    fourth.value = 'NONE';
    fifth.value = 'N/A';
    sixth.value = 'N/A';
}

Comment: Thanks for your help, still confused though.

Comment: I updated the answer, but basically when `pupulateInputs` is called it means that `first.value` is greater than `0`, so you can do whatever logic you need at that point.